# Alternative search engine with independent web crawler

Tags: web-apps, hosted, search-engine

Which web search engines match the following requirements?

1. Search results don't pull from Google, Bing, Yahoo, Yandex, Ask,
   AOL, Baidu, or Entireweb results. Results must pull from its own web
   crawler & database.
2. Allows search queries containing "exact phrase(s)".

I've found that:

- Peekier.com and mojeek.com satisfy (1) but not (2).
- Deusu.org appears to be down, but it might have been good.
- Duckduckgo, Millionshort, and Startpage satisfy (2) but not (1).

Are there any that satisfy both (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search engine [Qwant](https://www.qwant.com/) seems to satisfy the criterion listed in this question.

EDIT: Update: The new, decentralized search engine [Dsearch](https://www.dsearch.com) is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The search engine https://dropicon.com meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try Searx and Yacy. Searx is metasearch and will suggest more engines. Google "searx instances xyz" Maybe gigablast?